# Why can't I use a variable in a postgres backslash command (\COPY)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following sql script:

`\COPY my_table (column_1, column_2) FROM :csv_file WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', ESCAPE '"');`

which I am calling from:

`psql -d $DB_NAME -f $SQL_FILE -v csv_file="$CSV_FILE"`

But it keeps looking for a file called ":csv_file". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can use copy straight away as well: `psql -c '\COPY ...'`

Comment: thanks. yeah this happens inside a longer sql BEGIN - COMMIT.

Comment: My guess is that you can't use a variable there any more than you could use a variable field name or table name in a SELECT statement.  You'll probably have to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), build the statement as a varchar, and then execute the string with `EXECUTE`.

Comment: You can use a psql variable in a table name or field name, as in `\set table pg_user \\ select * from :"table";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, variable substitution does work with meta-commands (starting with backslash), but `\copy` is an exception, as documented in psql's [manpage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> The syntax of this command is similar to that of the SQL COPY command.
>   All options other than the data source/destination are as specified
>   for COPY. Because of this, special parsing rules apply to the \copy
>   command. **In particular, psql's variable substitution rules and
>   backslash escapes do not apply**.

I disagree with @BaconBits comment to the question that plpgsql's `EXECUTE` could be the answer. A server-side statement, dynamic or otherwise, will not access the client-side file system, contrary to `\copy`. You may use `COPY` instead, but it requires to be superuser and that file to be accessible to the `postgres` user on the server.

I believe that to `\copy` from a variable filename, the variable must be injected into the script before `psql` reads it. You might integrate the SQL script into a shell script and feed it to `psql` as a patchable here-string, or filter it through `sed` or `perl` or any similar unix-ish method.